# .NET 3.5 SP1 network shares allow exe application to run

Tags: .net-3.5

I could probably find this out from somewhere else but thought it would be a nice question to have on stack overflow.

.NET 2.0 by default stopped managed exe's running from network shares despite the fact you can run unmanaged exe's.

I have seen mention's that this was changed in .NET 3.5 SP1

Is this true?

Would that include any dll's I assume so?

Would I need to recompile the app for 3.5 or would the 3.5 settings override a 2.0 app?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this was changed in 3.5. You don't have to change anything, it "just works" as long as the client has 3.5 SP1

http://blogs.msdn.com/vancem/archive/2008/08/13/net-framework-3-5-sp1-allows-managed-code-to-be-launched-from-a-network-share.aspx