# C# network connection running from shared drive

Tags: c#, network-share

I'm trying to read web resource fron within the C# code. Unfortunately the code is valid only when running from local drive and throws exception when running from network share (and that's what I need).

```
The underlying connection was closed: Unable to connect to the remote server.
   in System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   .........
Caused by: 
An invalid argument was supplied
   in System.Net.Sockets.Socket..ctor(AddressFamily addressFamily, SocketType socketType, ProtocolType protocolType)
   in System.Net.ServicePoint.GetConnection(PooledStream PooledStream, Object owner, Boolean async, IPAddress& address, Socket& abortSocket, Socket& abortSocket6, Int32 timeout)
   in System.Net.PooledStream.Activate(Object owningObject, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback)
   in System.Net.Connection.CompleteStartConnection(Boolean async, HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest)
```

I've tried code similar to (this throws the exception):

```
request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
```

as well as direct socket connection according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2b86d684.

I have a suspicion there is some sort of security setting in Windows that prevents network connections. Is it possible to solve this? Via AD policy? Or something in my code?

Comment: Did you debug through? What `url` throws? Does the same URL causes the app to throw when it runs locally?

Comment: Maybe this can help : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/josefve/archive/2009/10/20/net-code-access-security-and-using-a-network-drive-or-a-unc-path-for-your-assembly.aspx, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1047243/net-code-access-security-useful-or-just-overcomplicated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could start here [The Project Location is Not Trusted Dialog Box](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2bkwxc%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). Quote:

> By default, a UNC path is not a trusted location for a project. You can modify the security policy of the file share to prevent this dialog box from appearing. For more information, see [Configuring Security Policy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c9c2y1w%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, that was the way. We've just tested it and everything works like a charm.